# Объясните что не так с псевдоэлементами after и как сделать правильно

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть код

```css
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #F00;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 59px;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}

h2:after {
  background: #D10A0A;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 90%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="action">Хит продаж</h2>
```

Не понимаю, почему псевдоэлемент при любом значении `z-index` получается по слоям выше, чем сам элемент. 
Получается вот такая ерунда, как на фотографии:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: 1. А как вам бы хотелось? 2. B заголовке вопроса идёт речь про before, а в коде про after, почему?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Псевдоэлемент `h2:after` создаётся **внутри** элемента `h2` и поэтому не может оказаться **под** ним.

Попробуйте добавить внутрь ещё один элемент, который будет перекрывать ваш `h2:after`. Например, так:

```css
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 59px;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}

h2:after {
  background: #D10A0A;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 90%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

h2 span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Хит продаж</span></h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L8cxwun5/

Answer (score 1):

[Z-index and transform](http://katydecorah.com/code/z-index-and-transform/)

```css
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #F00;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 59px;  
  transform: rotate(35deg);  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform: none;  
  -ms-transform-style: none;
}

h2:after {
  background: #D10A0A;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;  
  transform: rotate(150deg) translateZ(-20px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) translateZ(-20px);
  width: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  left: 90%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="action">Хит продаж</h2>
```

Comment: А как быть с IE?

Comment: @alenkins - preserve-3d не поддерживается в ie11 http://caniuse.com/#search=transform-style.